# SPARK LR binaryclass,i cant distinct the precision between overall precision and precisionbylabels

Tags: apache-spark, linear-regression, precision-recall

I have a model of LR, and test it on testData. Now I should be calculating the precision of the result.

I can get precision:

```
 val precision = metrics.precision 
 precision: Double = 0.9801503759398497
```

and also

```
 // Precision by labels
 Precision(0.0) = 0.9979625101874491
 Precision(1.0) = 0.9299655568312285
```

From the spark MLLIB, the first precision is defined as overall       statistics.

But it is also confusing what is the difference between precision and precision by labels? (precision defined as TRUE predictive rate).

Answer (score 0):

For vector data you're dealing with vectors of values, so you might want to compute precision not only when the whole vector was predicted correctly/incorrectly but also do this for each component (label) of the vector.

From the [Apache Spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-evaluation-metrics.html#label-based-metrics):

> Overall precision measures precision across all labels - the number of
>   times any class was predicted correctly (true positives) normalized by
>   the number of data points. Precision by label considers only one
>   class, and measures the number of time a specific label was predicted
>   correctly normalized by the number of times that label appears in the
>   output.